# Opinion on aesthetics of this symbol

Tags: symbols, equations

I am trying to decide on a symbol for a particular mathematical quantity, it has three different types of indices and I'm running out of places to put sub-scripts/super-scripts. I have a few ideas, but would like input on what looks best (or any additional ideas you may have). Since you are all typesetting experts, and anyone who uses TeX likely has some affinity for aesthetics, I figured this was a good place to ask. Here are my ideas so far:

[image: SomeIdeas]

For context, the symbol is used in equations similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I feel that this question doesn't fall within the scope of TeX.SE.

Comment: This question isn't based on fact, or a problem you need to resolve. It's entirely opinion based.

Comment: You will find all of these in the literature - it is opinion and subject area conventions which is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely favor (1). 5 and 6 are out of the question IMHO, far too ugly and unreadable. Maybe I could think of trying $J_{i, k_1, k_3}$, but for telling the reader the intent of the formula, I still think (1) is the best.